# Syfmony2 sonata adminBundle without create action

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata

Is it possible to generate admin using sonata adminbundle without create action?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [disable action in sonata admin bundle CRUD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288519/disable-action-in-sonata-admin-bundle-crud)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use in your admin class:

```
protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
{
    $collection->remove('create');
}
```