# disable action in sonata admin bundle CRUD

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

IS there a simple way to disable some CRUD actions for given admin class? E.g. I just want a list of users added via front-end without the option to manually add them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syfmony2 sonata adminBundle without create action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923343/syfmony2-sonata-adminbundle-without-create-action)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In your admin class :

```
protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
{
    // to remove a single route
    $collection->remove('delete');
    // OR remove all route except named ones
    $collection->clearExcept(array('list', 'show'));
}
```

Also use routeCollection at top of admin class

```
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection;
```

Docs : http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/routing.html#removing-a-single-route

Comment: How about if you needed to remove a route only when user is not assigned certain role?

Comment: This works for one type of user, but if multiple users have different roles, the action gets saved in cache. On switching of roles, the cache is loaded and the roles are not checked.