# Unable to find template "SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list__action_show.html.twig"

Tags: symfony, twig, sonata-admin

Error showed :

```
Unable to find template "SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list__action_show.html.twig" in SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig at line 23.
```

Configure entity for only show list(remove create, edit and delete routes) and showed this error, i find this template in sonata admin bundle but no exists, please help me with this issue.

Comment: How do you remove routes? Do you use method like http://stackoverflow.com/a/18290073/118593?

Comment: yes I do, but the second way is better, the first no clean the updated option in show-form, the real issue is the naming `show` vs `view` is very ambiguous, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is really no template called: `SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list__action_show.html.twig`

Your problem is not in routes, but in declaring wrong inline action in `configureListFields` method. The inline action should be called `view` so the `SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list__action_view.html.twig` will be called.

The inline actions should be declared like this:

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
            //... some other fields ...

            // add "show" link in each row of table
            ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
                'actions' => array(
                    'view' => array(),
                )
            ))
    ;
}
```